# Can't type passphrase to decrypt disk

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, macbook-pro, ecryptfs

Just wiped out everything on my Macbook Pro Retina Early-2015 (Macbook12,1 or something) and installed Ubuntu. Had to use `acpi=off` and `nodmraid` just to get the USB stick to boot.

I wanted to have full-disk encryption, so I selected that. However, I boot up to my Ubuntu install and I cannot type my passphrase! It just prompts me to "Please unlock disk sda3_crypt". I can use the arrow keys in Grub prior to the decryption screen. What should I try? (I don't want to have an unencrypted install if at all possible)

I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Edit your question to add the infos about the ubuntu version you're using...

Comment: Just tried an unencrypted install, cannot type in my password there either

Comment: The next thing I'm looking into is changing the grub config of the install to include acpi=off and nodmraid, but I can only do that from the live usb and I'm having trouble running update-grub

Comment: I am having same issues with Ubuntu 15 in a Windows Hyper-V.

Comment: I'm also having this issue on Hyper-V. Did you find a solution Ethan?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to this.  The problem is the keyboard driver isn't loading or something, so, i found if i put the ubuntu iso in the dvd drive, then go into recovery mode from grub, then go to boot normally I can pass this issue and type in my password in the command line.